# How to have minimizable sub-panels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, panel

How to provide minimizable sub-panels?

[image]

As you can see in the image in one pane, there are 4 menus (Don't know what they are) and they are minimizable when clicked on the arrow next to the titles. I'm not sure if this is Swing component or easily implementable.

Comment: What happens when all 4 are expanded?  Does a vertical scroll-bar appear?

Comment: Oh right.  Thanks for expanding on that. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.coderanch.com/t/344454/GUI/java/Accordion-Widget

or

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/pluggable_accordion

You can also try to find by "java swing accordion"